# ObjectStateManager couldn't recognize the object entry

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, objectstatemanager

I have the following code..

```
else if (p.EntityKey != null)
                        {
                            db.ApplyPropertyChanges(p.EntityKey.EntitySetName, new TableName_Entity()

                            {
                                AccountName =Profile.UserName,
                                Mx = null,
                                Sx = null,
                                Lx = null,
                                LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow

                            });
```

For this piece I am getting error like "The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type."

Tried bit of digging, but couldn't understand the exact reason.
Adding further before it was working perfectly but later I have added LastUpdated column in the table thus started giving the above mentioned error.

Comment: caution...  api method `ApplyPropertyChanges` is obsolete since .net 4.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.applypropertychanges(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: given we are looking at a "snippet", i can only guess.   You have 2 contexts on the go. Object p is in the Other context.